# I just made a new PC, and Ubuntu isn’t booting properly

Tags: boot, system-installation, rufus

I just made a new PC with no OS on it. I wanted my first OS to be Ubuntu.

I have finished the PC (btw I’m using an external WiFi USB, which requires that I download drivers, which I’ll do afterwards I have an OS; therefore, I don’t have internet on my PC rn), and it boots into BIOS perfectly.

I made a bootable Ubuntu stick according to their website, using Rufus. Whenever I boot up my PC with my stick in it, it opens a page that has a bunch of options, including “try/install Ubuntu.” However, whenever I do that, it just goes to a black screen.

I tried to do `nomodeset`, but it just gets stuck saying “running command.” I’ve left it alone for hours and nothing happens. I’ve tried everything I can find and nothing has worked. I’ve spent so much time and money on making a new PC, and now the part I thought would be easy isn’t working at all.

Comment: Even if new, do you have latest firmware for UEFI & SSD? What brand/model motherboard? What video card/chip? Some require extra settings. While it should work with UEFI Secure boot on, many find it easier with it off for now. Some very new systems may need newer kernel & drivers.

Comment: So I don’t know if I have the latest firmware. I would assume so because I bought everything new, but with no OS I haven’t been able to check. My motherboard is an ASUS Prime B760 Plus. My GPU is an AMD Radeon RX 7600.

Comment: See this for commands in Linux to see firmware versions. Then compare to vendors site. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493685&p=14170710#post14170710  ASUS PRIME Z790-P WIFI motherboard.
https://www.phoronix.com/review/intel-14600k-14900k-linux  Older link with various issues on older card. Most should be resolved with newer version of Ubuntu. ASUS PRIME B350M-E major issues
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Raven-Ridge-Mobo-Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)